# Add button click event with the menu item instead of navigate url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create dynamic menuitem driven from the database in ASP.NET. After creating the menuitem, I want to bind them with the button click event for each of the menuitem passing a parameter instead of NavigateUrl option.

```
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem
    {
        Value = row["MenuId"].ToString(),
        Text = row["Title"].ToString(),
        //NavigateUrl = row["Url"].ToString(),
       //some logic to bind to onclick event
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add the click event to each `menuItem` you have to add it to the `Menu` and in the click event you verify which `menuItem` was clicked.

So make sure you add the `MenuItemClick` to your menu like this :

```
menu.MenuItemClick += Menu_MenuItemClick;
```

Then you can have a function that will create the `MenuItems` and in the event handler you can have something like this to verify which one was selected :

```
private void Menu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.Text == "text1")
    {
        //Do what you need
    }
    else if(e.Item.Text == "text2")
    {
        //Do what you need
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. I had to add OnMenuItemClick event to Menu such as OnMenuItemClick="Menu_OnClick".Based on the click, I checked

```
protected void Menu_OnClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = e.Item.Value.ToString();
       //OR
        // string value = e.Item.Text.ToString(); 
        //some logic
}
```